# Find element containing "img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_" and ".jpg"

Tags: selenium

The element on the page look like this:

```
<p>
          
          img/raster/bb170663-af7a-4039-857d-323fbe42d57c/img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_3.jpg
          
          
          
            </p>
```

I'm trying to find it no matter what verion it mentions.

```
xpath = '//p[contains(., img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_) and //p[contains(., jpg)]'

file_name_label_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

Exception:

```
/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/venv/bin/python /home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2020.3.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 44503 --file /home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/admin_upload_aux.py
Connected to pydev debugger (build 203.7148.72)
Id изображение. Если добавляем новое изображение, нажмите Enter: >? bb170663-af7a-4039-857d-323fbe42d57c
python-BaseException
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2020.3.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1477, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/michael/Documents/pycharm-community-2020.3.3/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/admin_upload_aux.py", line 199, in <module>
    init()
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/admin_upload_aux.py", line 194, in init
    sm.upload_files(pk=an_id)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/admin_upload_aux.py", line 157, in upload_files
    self._upload_responsive_images(files=files,
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/admin_upload_aux.py", line 87, in _upload_responsive_images
    file_name_label_element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/michael/PycharmProjects/admin_upload_aux/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //p[contains(., img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_) and //p[contains(., jpg)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//p[contains(., img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_) and //p[contains(., jpg)]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.82)
```

The whole html: https://dpaste.com/57UM65D6D

Could you help me write a proper xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//p[starts-with(normalize-space(text()),"img/raster/bb170663-af7a-4039-857d-323fbe42d57c/img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_") and contains(text(),".jpg") ]
```

use the above xpath , . will check for all current elements all nodes also , change '.' to text

Comment: It finds wrong element: https://cdn1.radikalno.ru/uploads/2021/3/15/14740965251c9ed1829a35b9898ab23d-full.png It has found raster_origina.jpg. Can it somehow use OR instead of AND here? In this case it just have found the first jpg. – Kifsif 2 mins ago   Edit   Delete

Comment: which is the right element is it under the same parent ?

Comment: No. Parents are different. I've uploaded the whole html to the question.

Answer (score 0):

can your provide url page?
I would suggest using smth like that:

```
xpath = '//p[contains(text(), img_width_687_height_517_dpr_4x_ver_)
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
print(el.text)
```

Comment: The file extension is not used in your answer. It can't be correct. I'll upload the whole html to the question. I can't provide you with the url.

Comment: @Kifsif might I didn't get the question right, but seems like it should not make difference at all, but if you say that it's incorrect, ok)